# Collapsing a TextBlock within a ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf

at the moment I have conditional visibilities on all the `RadMenuItems`. If the selected item is active then display the all `RadMenuItems`, otherwise hide some. I can successfully collapse `MenuItems` without any issues. within my `ContextMenus` I have menu items and some text blocks for titles. The menu items collapsed completely fine, the textblocks when collapse leave an empty space where the area is remains highlight-able.

I'm wondering how do I collapse an inner `TextBlock` within `ContextMenu` or what is the proper way to display titles within contextmenus

```
<telerik:RadContextMenu 
    <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="New Appointment"/>

    <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Delete Appointment"
                         Visibility="{Binding SelectedAppointment.ContextVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

    <TextBlock           Text="Time Markers"
                         Visibility="{Binding SelectedAppointment.ContextVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

    <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Move Appointment"
                         Visibility="{Binding SelectedAppointment.ContextVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
/>
```

Converter

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool) value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Tried wrapping textblock around a stackpanel like below and had the same result

```
<StackPanel    Visibility="{Binding SelectedAppointment.ContextVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"> 
    <TextBlock    Text="Time Markers"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Let's see your `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` code..

Comment: Hi @Cameron, updated.

Comment: Did you try to wrap the `TextBlock` with some element (a `StackPanel`) and bind the visibility to the `Stackpanel`. I once had this issue with a TextBlock inside a Treeview.

Comment: Hi @jHilscher, same result unfortunated =(